# How to set background image size match with foreground image

Tags: css

I have a background image added and I am trying to set background image to be 80% of foreground image. Not sure how to do that.

Current setup:

[image]

code behind:

```
.field-content.main-hero {
    background: url(/themes/custom/mytheme/assets/images/white-pink-background.png) no-repeat left/contain !important;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    background-attachment: scroll !important;
}
```

the background image is rightnow on its original size. How can i adjust it dynamically to be 80% of foreground image?

Comment: background-size percentages apply to the background positioning area. So the "foreground image" would have to determine the dimensions of the element you want to apply this to in the first place then.

Comment: Can you pls guide towards an example?

Comment: Try and wrap the image into an inline element, and apply the background image to that.